# When using MSGaraph API to get messages from channel it returns me all the messages including deleted one

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using MS graph API to get messages from a channel, it gives the list of messages including the deleted one. Is there a way to filter it?

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams//channels//messages?$top=50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side filtering of channel message is not supported. Only supported query parameters are `$top` and `$expand`.

Client side filtering seems to be not good option right now because according [this issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/17883) `deletedDateTime` property is null for deleted messages (probably due to a bug), so you can't find out whether the message was deleted or not.

Resources:

[Query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I also read about that in the issues thread of the MS graph.